# By default, Laravel migrations makes all my table columns not null. How to allow some columns to be null?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to be able to upload an image without having to give it description, but to still be able to if you wanted. Currently my migrations are making all my columns not null which is creating this problem for me.

Comment: include your migration file for better understanding

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far? Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Please post the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [nullable()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#column-modifiers) on migrations :

```
$table->string('description')->nullable();
```